# How to count different elements inside a column in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to implement one misure which is to be used to count the number of "1" inside a column. In this column are contained 1, 0 and NULL. Which DAX formula do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Count 1's = 
    CALCULATE( COUNT( 'Table'[Column1] ),
        'Table'[Column1] = 1 )
```

Use calculate to specify what you want (count)  and then give it parameters, which in this case is where the column values = 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very simple in sql but I'm relatively new in DAX.

Comment: Check out [Enterprise DNA](https://enterprisedna.co/) if you want to learn more. They have several free courses that will get you a solid grasp on DAX.